# r - check if every column is na

Tags: r, na

I have a list of columns within a dataframe which where i want to check if all those columns are `NA` and create a new column which tells me if they are `NA` or not.

Here is an example of it working with one column, where `Any_Flag` is my new column:

```
ItemStats_2014$Any_Flag <- ifelse(is.na(ItemStats_2014$Item_Flag_A), "Y", "N")
```

When i try to run the check over multiple columns, I am getting what i expect:

```
ItemStats_2014$Any_Flag <- ifelse(all(is.na(ItemStats_2014[ ,grep("Flag", names(ItemStats_2014), value = T)])), "Y", "N")
```

It returns everything to be false or "N".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Data**

```
set.seed(1)
data <- c(LETTERS, NA)
df <- data.frame(Flag_A = sample(data), Flag_B = sample(data), 
                 C = sample(data), D = sample(data), Flag_E = sample(data))

df <- rbind(NA, df)
```

**Code**

Identifying all NAs per row:

```
> df$All_NA <- apply(df[, grep("Flag", names(df))], 1, function(x) all(is.na(x)))
> head(df)
  Flag_A Flag_B    C    D Flag_E All_NA
1   <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   <NA>   TRUE
2      H      K    B    T      Y  FALSE
3      J      W    C    K      P  FALSE
4      O      I    H    I   <NA>  FALSE
5      V      L    M    S      R  FALSE
6      E      N    P    E      I  FALSE
```

Identifying at least one NA per row:

```
> df$Any_NA <- apply(df[, grep("Flag", names(df))], 1, function(x) anyNA(x))
> head(df)
  Flag_A Flag_B    C    D Flag_E Any_NA
1   <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA>   <NA>   TRUE
2      H      K    B    T      Y  FALSE
3      J      W    C    K      P  FALSE
4      O      I    H    I   <NA>   TRUE
5      V      L    M    S      R  FALSE
6      E      N    P    E      I  FALSE
```

Comment: this it what i have been trying to do, but i keep getting this error: Error in apply(ItemStats_2014[, grep("Item_Flag", names(ItemStats_2014))],  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Comment: Can you paste the output of `str(ItemStats_2014, list.len = 10)` ?

Comment: i assume you are looking for the structure of those fields. there are many columns. The ones i am trying to use in the function are characters. i am actually using an if statement to do the opposite of you any flag output Just so your request makes a little more sense.

Comment: ` $ Item_Flag_A                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_B                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_C                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_N                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_O                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_P                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_R                   : chr  "R" NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_V                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Item_Flag_Z                   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...`

Comment: Make sure your object is a data.frame or matrix, not a list. Can you verify that pls? `Str()` function usually tells that as the first info, but I missed that in your pasting. Just see `dim()` or `class()`...

Comment: str(ItemStats_2014)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 19435 obs. of  151 variables:

Comment: That's it! You're dealing with 'data.table' object, so it require `dt[, <cols_selection>, with = F]`. Just add `, with = F` after the grep, yet inside the brackets.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the `grep` part is supposed to do, but here's a simpler way to accomplish what you want:

```
 apply(ItemStats_2014[, 2:10], MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) all(is.na(x)))
```

Replace `2:10` with whatever columns you want to check.

*Amendment:* If you want to detect which columns contain the word "Flag" rather than hard coding their indices -- which would be better anyway! -- I like the package `stringr` for working with text. You could do this to select your columns:

```
 library(stringr)
 MyCols <- which(str_detect(names(ItemStats_2014), "Flag"))
```

Now, replace `2:10` with `MyCols` in the `apply(...` code above.

Comment: the grep is intended to call out columns where 'Flag' is in the name. is there any way to format to [, 2:10] to find the columns with 'flag' in the name

Comment: here is he error i get with apply: Error in apply(ItemStats_2014[, grep("Flag", names(ItemStats_2014))],  : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length

Answer (score 3):

And a `data.table` way without any `apply` is:

```
library(arsenal)
library(data.table)

# dummy data
set.seed(1)
data = c(LETTERS, NA)
dt = data.table(Flag_A=sample(data), Flag_B = sample(data), C=sample(data), D=sample(data), Flag_E=sample(data))
dt = rbind(NA, dt)

# All-NA/Any-NA check
columns_to_check = names(dt)[grep('Flag', names(dt))]
dt[, AllNA:=allNA(.SD), by=1:nrow(dt), .SDcols = columns_to_check]
dt[, AnyNA:=anyNA(.SD), by=1:nrow(dt), .SDcols = columns_to_check]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are trying to test if a row (not a column) contains at least one NA.

Here a dataset

```
x = c(1:10, NA)
df = data.frame(A = sample(x), B = sample(x), C = sample(x))
```

And here a loop that test that with `anyNA`

```
df$Any_na = apply(df[,2:3], 1, anyNA)
df

    A  B  C Any_na
1  NA  8  9  FALSE
2   5  9 NA   TRUE
3   9  3 10  FALSE
4   7  5  1  FALSE
5   4  2  3  FALSE
6  10  4  6  FALSE
7   3  1  2  FALSE
8   6  6  5  FALSE
9   1 10  7  FALSE
10  2 NA  8   TRUE
11  8  7  4  FALSE
```

Comment: right a row but not of a whole data set. just the part of the dataset where 'Flag' is in the column name.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you get started :

```
# Sample dataframe
dfx <- data.frame(
x = c(21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, NA),
y = c(1449, 1814, 582, 582, 947, 183),
s = c(26.4, 28.7, 32, 25.3, NA, 25.7),
z = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
)

# Sapply works well here 
ifelse(sapply(dfx, function(x)all(is.na(x))) == TRUE, "Y","N")
```

output :

```
 x   y   s   z 
"N" "N" "N" "Y"
```